# Windows 7 Taskbar Right Click Options

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, right-click

I have a set of dictionaries installed on my computer. Unfortunately, they are all in separate programs (English-Italian and Italian-English are two separate programs).

I would like to add one dictionary to my Windows 7 Taskbar, and when I right click on it, I would like to get the option of selecting the dictionary I want.

To make it clear: Office Word is a "thing" on my taskbar and the documents I recently worked on appear when I right click on it. For my dictionaries, I would like a "recent" list but then with all my possible dictionaries in it.

I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

Something like application group in task bar? Try this: http://www.oneupindustries.com/bins/